# How to fix the disapearance on libpython3.8?

Tags: python, dependencies

1. I attempted the installation of ROCM 4.2 in my Ubuntu 20.04 so as to have OpenCL (amd-gpu) running in Blender. I proceeded used the guidance written on https://rocmdocs.amd.com/en/latest/Installation_Guide/Installation-Guide.html#installing-a-rocm-package-from-a-debian-repository where I proceeded with the commands. Until, ...

> yd@yd:~$ sudo apt install rocm-dkms
>
> Reading package lists...Done
>
> Building dependency tree... Done
>
> Reading state information... Done
>
> Some packages could not be installed. This
> may mean that you have requested an impossible situation or if you are
> using the unstable distribution that some required packages have not
> yet been created or been moved out of Incoming.
>
> The following
> information may help to resolve the situation:
>
> The following packages have unmet dependencies:  rocm-gdb : Depends:
> libpython3.8 but it is not installable E: Unable to correct problems,
> you have held broken packages.

2. As well somewhere else, installing FreeCad , I see the following message that seems to be related to the same problem:

[image]

3. Searching on the terminal for libpython* and versions, no 3.8 is to be found:  [pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/Zy5vhBy7Ws](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/Zy5vhBy7Ws)
4. Checking history of commands I did, I do not see anything related to libpython3.8: [pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/xyTsQHH5mK](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/xyTsQHH5mK)
5. Remark: Checking Ubuntu version, I do not see LTS mentioned. Is this a problem?
   [image]
6. From previous inquiry, I understood that the correct version of libpython3.8 on Ubuntu 20.04 is 3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04

How can I fix this libpython3.8 issue? Can I simply reinstall? If yes, how?

Your input is greatly appreciated. Thx in advance.

UPDATE: after reinstalling the OS, I still do not see libpython3.8

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)

Comment: I did reinstall Ubuntu so I cannot tell.  Thx tough. for future reference.  it might help someone ...